# Add images to stack exchange questions

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined

I still can't add images to questions here on this forum, I hit image upload (ctrl-g) it uploads and shows the image in a separate window and then the only thing I can click is "cancel and add another image". Or I can click outside the upload window, but then it does not upload. I can't click "use this image" or anything that would confirm the upload. I'm on a Mac using Safari (Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12))

Comment: Just FYI, this post might get migrated to "meta.Blender.StackExchange.com" Don't let that worry you, it's just a better place for meta-discussion ;-)

Comment: ...and welcome to Blender.SE!

Comment: We do not support [old versions of browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) - the current version of Safari is 9.1.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are ***Not*** forums. They use a very specific, Q&A format.

Answer (score 4):

You can only upload images in a **supported format**: jpg, PNG, tiff, bmp or gif.

If you try to upload an unsupported file type, should show you a warning :

[image]

Also, see if you can scroll around the new window that's created. You should see something like this:
[image]

It's possible that the button is just hidden at the bottom of the window. Lastly, try a different browser to find out if it's a browser compatibility issue.

Images are limited to 2Mb in size. For larger images or unsupported formats consider uploading to a different host and adding the link to it on your post.

Comment: Pngs work fine for me?

Comment: I use pngs for all my screen shots, works fine for me.

Comment: Same, op should probably try another browser.

Comment: @Matt PNGs, jpg and Gif files are supported.

Comment: My mistake. I thought I remembered trying to upload a png and getting rejected. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the keyboard shortcut doesn't work try using the icon to add images:

[image]

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for all the answers. Using the image button or the upload image brings up the window you show, and I see my image in it. I tried firefox in firefox I see the add image button. On a Safari it snaps the pop-up window right to the bottom right corner and there is no resizing that is going to help me to actually be able to click the add picture button. I guess I can't use Safai with Stack Exchange. I'll just use Firefox, than. Thanks again for the replies.

Answer (score -1):

With Safari don't works (I have a Mac), so try installing Google Chrome